# Is a multiform program sharing a class possible?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How do I get my sphereGUI.cs to use MyMath.cs?

Here is the line of code written on the sphereGUI.cs form `if (TriMath.IsNumeric(textBox1.Text) == true)`
Here is the error message: Error The name 'TriMath' does not exist in the current context   C:\Workspace\Cisc-2330-Labs\Lab6\Lab6\sphereGUI.cs  24  11  Lab6

[image: explorer]

Comment: Perhaps it is of a different namespace?  You may be missing a dependency.

Comment: Right click on TriMath and select "Resolve". This will add the appropriate namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey just check out this statement,

```
if (TriMath.IsNumeric(textBox1.Text) == true
```

Your class Name is `MyMath` according to snap and you are using `TriMath`?

1. Make sure the namespace is correct
2. Make Sure that the references required is added in the header section (like using...)

Comment: Thank you. The problem was that I named it TriMath and not MyMath.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure they are in same `Namespace`

For Form1.cs it should be

```
namespace Lab6
{
    class Form1:Form
    {
        //....
    }
}
```

For MyMath.cs

```
namespace Lab6
{
    class MyMath
    {
        //....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include a using statement that grabs the class from its namespace.